# Problems with multiple Node.js callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to solve a problem i've been having with a nodejs cronjob of mine. So basically, This request grabs my tracks from soundcloud, I loop through the results and put the data in a mongodb collection. This all works great, but now i'm adding another section to the site, so I need to grab some additional info from another collection.

I have a tracks collection, and an inventory collection. The track id is in both collections to relate the additional track data to the newly pulled tracks. **So my question is how can I get this additional track data in?** Below i have tried to loop through it and inject the data using mongoose's query.find() but the loops do not work together. The callback of the inventory query will run all in one for loop it seems... I'm not exactly sure whats going on there.

I'm pretty sure you can also inject a document from another collection by referencing it in the schema... but i'm unsure of how to get this working. This would obviously be a better solution as it won't require more code like this.

if anybody has any suggestions for me that would be great!

```
request({
url: url,
json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        var o = 1;

        for(i=0; i < body.tracks.length; i++){
            var last = (i + 1);
            var track = body.tracks[i];

            if( track.sharing == 'public'){
                var invData;
                var obj;

                db.model('inventory').find({id:track.id}).exec(function(err,item){
                    //console.log(item[0]);
                    invData = item[0];


                });


                console.log(invData, obj);

                obj = new TracksModel({
                    id: track.id,
                    sharing:track.sharing,
                    uri:track.uri,
                    description:track.description,
                    created_at:track.created_at,
                    duration:track.duration,
                    title:track.title,
                    description:track.description,
                    order: o,
                    inventory_data: invData
                });





                o++;

                obj.save(function (err) {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log('Track inserted successfully');
                    } else {
                        throw err;
                    }
                });

                if(last == body.length){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        console.log("Automatically closing database connection after 5 seconds");
                        db.close();
                    }, 5000);
                }

            }

        }

} else {
    console.log('An error has occurred: ', error);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are treating the query callback is wrong. You are assuming that the code starting from "console.log(invData, obj);" will be executed immediately after the db.model.find. That not the correct notion of Callback. How must put that code inside the exec callback function. You may have to use a closure.
Something like:

```
if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    var o = 1;

    for(i=0; i < body.tracks.length; i++){
        var last = (i + 1);
        var track = body.tracks[i];

        if( track.sharing == 'public'){

            (function(track,last,o){

                var invData;
                var obj;

                db.model('inventory').find({id:track.id}).exec(function(err,item){
                    //console.log(item[0]);
                    invData = item[0];

                    console.log(invData, obj);

                    obj = new TracksModel({
                        id: track.id,
                        sharing:track.sharing,
                        uri:track.uri,
                        description:track.description,
                        created_at:track.created_at,
                        duration:track.duration,
                        title:track.title,
                        description:track.description,
                        order: o,
                        inventory_data: invData
                    });

                    obj.save(function (err) {
                        if (!err) {
                            console.log('Track inserted successfully');
                        } else {
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });

                    if(last == body.length){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            console.log("Automatically closing database connection after 5 seconds");
                            db.close();
                        }, 5000);
                    }
                });
            }(track,last,o);    

            o++;
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: So what is the purpose of `(function(track,last,o){}(track,last,o);`? If i understand exec correctly, it executes the callback right away, in that same `for` loop cycle? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: The find command is asynchronous, and therefore, the exec will not execute right away. The exec is the callback function of the find, and will only be called when find is terminated. In your code, all the code that is after the find is called right away. The (function(track,last,o){}(track,last,o) is to access the correct values of the for inside the exec function. If you want i can better explain why the use of this function with an example.

Comment: implemented your code and it worked great! You are just missing a closing bracket after the anon function `}(track,last,o));`. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
var utils = require('restberry-utils');

var Inventory = mongoose.model('Inventory');
var Track = mongoose.model('Track');

request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log('An error has occurred: ', error);
        return;
    }
    utils.forEachAndDone(body.track, function(track, iter) {
        if (track.sharing !== 'public') {
            iter();
            return;
        }
        Inventory.findOne({ id: track.id }, function(err, item) {
            new Track({
                id: track.id,
                sharing: track.sharing,
                uri: track.uri,
                description: track.description,
                created_at: track.created_at,
                duration: track.duration,
                title: track.title,
                description: track.description,
                order: o,
                inventory_data: item,
            }).save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    console.log('Track inserted successfully');
                    iter();
                }
            })
        });
    }, function() {
        console.log('Done!');
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Automatically closing database connection after 5 seconds");
            db.close();
        }, 5000);
    })
});
```

Comment: Interesting! Do you find restberry's functions really helpful? I like to keep things light but if it's going to make my life easier i have no problems putting it in. Thanks for the reply! Still trying to wrap my head around writing node like this.

Comment: I'm the author of restberry so I think it's useful ;) the forEachAndDone method is nice for when you need to loop through an array and then do some operation at the end, that is always tricky with callbacks. It's not a very difficult method to implement yourself so you might do that, didn't want to do it for this answer why I choose to import utils which I use a lot :)

Comment: oh cool, yes getting callbacks going properly is a bit difficult for me in node.. i'll check it out! Thanks!

Comment: @ShanRobertson cool, glad I could help. mind marking this as the right answer :)